# how to make android app always listen to the server

Tags: android, mysql

I want to write an app that whenever user 1 touches the "buzz button" in the app,
immediately user 2's phone vibrates.
I have written the app code and when user 1 clicks on the button, a request sends to the server via post method and the database updates.
so I can send the vibrate request to the sever.
but what should I do to force the app always listen to the server that when a request sent to it, phone vibrates.
And if you recommend any other ways please share with me!
I also need to store the buzz history in a SQL

Comment: Sounds like a decent use case for Firebase messaging.

Answer (score 0):

To manually handle background process use Service:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

And when event occurs use Broadcast:(to send events to other Fragment/Activity/Application)
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

to hear the broadcast events Register it to Receiver:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

JobScheduler can also be used in modern android applications:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler

Comment: thank you. do you know how can I send a request like "buzz=true" to the app from server?